# Is is possible Launch Alert Dialog from BroadcastReceiver?

Tags: java, android, android-layout, alarmmanager

I am creating an Alarm App, On the specified time, `AlarmBroadcast` launches.
I want to add `Alert Dialog` on the specified time.

This is what i have done.

```
public class AlarmBrodcast extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {


        final AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(context.getApplicationContext()).create();
        alertDialog.setTitle("Delete Remainder");
        alertDialog.setMessage("Are you sure you want to Delete this Remainder");
        alertDialog.setButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_POSITIVE, "Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                alertDialog.dismiss();

            }
        });


        alertDialog.setButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_NEGATIVE, "No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                alertDialog.dismiss();
            }
        });


        alertDialog.show();
```

This gives me following error message.

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate receiver
>   com.example.taha.alarmproject.AlarmBrodcast:
>   java.lang.ClassCastException:
>   com.example.taha.alarmproject.AlarmBrodcast cannot be cast to
>   android.content.BroadcastReceiver

**Edit**
**MainActivity**

```
      Intent intent = new Intent(this, AlarmBrodcast.class);
        intent.putExtra("message", "Alarm Message 00001");
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(
                this.getApplicationContext(), 234324243, intent, 0);

        AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
 /*       alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, cal.getTimeInMillis(), pendingIntent);*/


        alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, System.currentTimeMillis()
                + (i * 1000), pendingIntent);


        Toast.makeText(this, "Alarm set in " + i + " seconds", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

I also tried to launch an `Activity` from `BrodcastReceiver`, and it failed to launch that as well.

Comment: Did you add the `receiver` in the manifest ?

Comment: yes i added, I was successfully able to print Toast Message

Comment: please post the code where you instantiate the broadcast receiver

Comment: @Lino have updated my question

Comment: So you have an Activity that you start everything up right?

Comment: @Eenvincible In `Broadcast Receiver` if i remove `AlertNotification` and add `Toast`. It works fine

Comment: I would suggest you try my answer below!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One simple solution to this would be to use an `Event`. This is how you do it with a nifty little library I use in my projects:

```
compile 'org.greenrobot:eventbus:3.0.0'
```

Add that single line to your `build.gradle` (module-level) file.

The idea here is to enable your `AlarmBroadcast` to notify some `Activity` class when `onReceive` is called.

Create a `Plain Old Java Object (POJO)` class to represent your Event!

```
public class BroadCastEvent{
  private boolean isCompleted;

  BroadCastEvent(boolean completed){
     this.isCompleted = completed;
  }

  //getter
  public boolean isCompleted(){
     return this.isCompleted;
  }
}
```

Now, inside `onReceive` method of your `AlarmBroadcast` class:

```
EventBus.getDefault().post(new BroadCastEvent(true));
```

Next, in your activity, register to listen for this event like this:

```
EventBus.getDefault().register(this);
```

Then override this method:

```
public void onEvent(BroadCastEvent event){
   if(event.isCompleted()){
      //show your dialog here or start next activity
   }
}
```

Next, unregister eventbus inside onDestroy method:

```
@Override
public void onDestroy(){
   super.onDestroy();

   EventBus.getDefault().unregister(this);
}
```

This decouples your code and allows you to make your AlarmBroadcast class a `Publisher` and your activity a `Subscriber`!

I hope this helps and please let me know how it goes!